# Two Sections 100% Height of Parent Div

Tags: html, css

I have a specific layout that is causing me HUGE headaches. Here is an image:

[image]

My goal is to have the "Side panel" ALWAYS equal the height of the container. The "Enrollment Application" section is at 100% height already.

**Current Markup**

```
<body>
    <div id="container" class="pure-g">

        <div class="pure-u-md-1-4 pure-u-1 panel" id="left-panel">
            <div class="panel-row">
                <div class="panel p">
                    <div class="inner-panel">
                        <div class="panel-logo">
                             "Logo here text"
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-row">
                <div class="panel p">
                    <div class="inner-panel">
                        <nav class="panel">

                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="right-panel" class="pure-u-md-3-4 pure-u-1 panel p">
            <div class="inner-panel">
                <header class="pure-g">
                    <div class="pure-u-md-1-4 pure-u-1 header-logo">
                        LOGO Would go here, of course.
                    </div>
                    <div class="pure-u-md-3-4 pure-u-1 header-title">
                        <h1>Consumers Energy</h1>
                        <h1><strong>CARE 3.0 Program</strong></h1>
                        <h1>Enrollment Application</h1>
                    </div>
                </header>

                <div id="content">
                    "Enrollment application text..."
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

**Current CSS**

```
.panel {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
}
.panel.p {
  padding: 3px;
}
.panel .panel-row {
  display: table-row;
}
.panel .inner-panel {
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Here is an alternative fiddle to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/3c3tqo3e/ but I really don't want to use a table...

**Q** How can we stack two divs and make their heights = 100% of parent? The "Logo here.." section will be an auto height.

**NOTE** I would *really* prefer an answer that is responsive-friendly. I am using PureCSS for the sections. (This means that absolute positioning is not preferred) Also, strongly prefer *just* css/html. Thanks!

Comment: Please post your code or create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: It's a mess :/ but will do

Comment: Just try to pick out the relevant code @karns

Answer (score 2):

I have created a demo for you, but it will work on all [modern browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=flex) only. and you might have to read [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex) and its [demos](http://dipaksblogonline.blogspot.in/2014/05/css-flexbox-explained-with-examples.html) in details to make your work more meaningful in terms of performance and maintenance.

Also read on [calc() here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

HTML:

```
<main>
    <aside>
        <div class="logo">Logo</div>
        <div class="aside-content">Other Content</div>
    </aside>
    <section>Section</section>
</main>
```

CSS:

```
html, body{ height: 100%; }
main{
    height: 100%; background: teal; padding: 2em; box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex; flex-direction: row; 
}
aside{
    height: inherit; margin: 0 1em 0 0; width: 200px;
}
aside .logo{
    background: #fff; height: 140px;
}
aside .aside-content{
    background: #fff; height: calc(100% - 150px); margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}

main section{
    height: inherit; background: #fff; flex-grow: 2;
}
```

Demo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vpqqyo9L/1/

**Edit:**

Here's one for IE9: http://jsfiddle.net/vpqqyo9L/3/

Comment: Forgot to mention IE9 support is needed :/ but +1 since I could fallback to something else.

Comment: Still doesn't support IE9 - looks all janky